# Routing Tables: What is the effect of the RTF_IFSCOPE flag?

Tags: freebsd, osx, routing

(Related to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16612/mac-pro-splitting-network-traffic-based-on-destination/16677#16677) I posted a while ago on apple.stackexchange.)

What is the difference between the following two routing table entries:

```
default            E.F.G.H     UGSc            0        0     en1
default            E.F.G.H     UGScI          25        0     en1
```

(Where E.F.G.H is some gateway IP address.) Specifically what effect does the `RTF_IFSCOPE` flag have on the routing table entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `route` command's `-ifscope` option to bind a route to a specific interface.  This lets you create multiple routes that point to the same destination, differentiated only by which interface is in play.  Routes so bound show up in `netstat` output with the `I` flag.