# Why is my traceroute hitting the wrong gateway?

Tags: routing, traceroute

**What "Should" Happen**
I want traffic to Google to go through `en0` (Mac) and hit gateway A (let's say IP = `123.456.789.000`). I have another route setup for `en3` and I don't want to mess with that.

**Tried:**

```
sudo route add -host 173.194.121.54 123.456.789.000 -ifscope en0
```

**Output from that was:**

`netstat -nr` showed:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            234.567.89.10      UGSc           35       14     en3
default            123.456.789.000    UGSc           35       14     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             13     6073     lo0
173.194.121.54     123.456.789.000    UGHSI           0        0     en0
```

Groovy, no?

Tried `ping`, Google unreachable. Tried `traceroute` and saw:

```
traceroute to 173.194.121.54 (173.194.121.54), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  234.567.89.10 (234.567.89.10)  1.043 ms !N  0.883 ms !N  0.862 ms !N
```

No bueno.

I would expect to see `traceroute` start at the right gateway (`123.456.789.000`) but instead it's going through the wrong gateway and I'd guess the wrong device.

Where did I go wrong?

**Edit:** Apologies, I've been trying a lot of things, hard to tell one output from the other.

Comment: I am not familiar with `-ifscope` but I found some information about it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/routing-tables-what-is-the-effect-of-the-rtf-ifscope-flag) and it I would say it doesn't have anything to do with what you want. Have you tried *without* that flag?

Comment: You can't have two default gateways (at least, not like this). The definition of a "default gateway" is the gateway that is used if there is no explicit route. Singular.

Comment: @roaima, not something I did. This is just what happens on Macs with two network adapters. It sorts by specificity, than list order. If I move my WiFi above my ethernet in the preference GUI it still has two defaults but they're in a different order.

Comment: @Celada I have, and it still routes to the wrong gateway. I tried using `gw <ip> dev <device>` at the end of the `route add` and Mac just doesn't like that (which makes sense since it's a Debian/Ubuntu syntax)

Comment: @Celada the `-ifscope` was just another shot in the dark, but it at least changed the `netif` in the `netstat -nr` output so I thought I was on the right track.

Comment: @JasonNichols Please don't use `dev <device>` and also edit your question because I think there is something wrong with it. You added a route to `17.194.121/24` via `123.456.789.000` and you ended up with a routng table entry for `173.194.121/24` via `10.10.171.254`. This seems like you combined the `route` command and `netstat` output from completely different trials.

Comment: @Celada updated. I'm using a placeholder address for the internal IP's (obviously, since neither `123.456.789.000` or `234.567.89.10` are valid) in the question, just forgot to replace one. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: you still have 17.194.121/24 (in the route command) vs. 17**3**.194.121/24 (in the netstat output)

Comment: The `H` flag in `UGHSI` means 173.194.121.0 is being interpreted as a host address, not a net address.What was the exact `route` command you typed?